# Fitting a vectorlayer to an orthomosaic

Tags: coordinate-system, vector

I have an orthomosaic, made by drone on with an AI Detector marked all visible plants. The orthomosaic was computed which GCPs collected by emlid reach rs+ with RTK.

As result i got a shape point layer with all plants. The orthomosaic and the resulting point shape layer are in CRS EPSG4326.

From the planing office i got also a  line shape in CRS UTM 33N. This line shape layer contains all information and attributes from each plot of this field. It was used for seeding.
Each plot has two rows of corn. Out of this line shape layer i computed polygons to count the points in each polygon. The process works good so far.

But there is one problem. The line shape fits very good from east to west and is located in the middle of the plots on the walking way. But in the south in runs over the edge of the plots. In the image you can see it. The line runs over the interrupted corn line. The should be in de middle of the wy between the polts and also directly in front of the interrupted rows.

How can i move the polygon layer? I have tried it moving the shape, but when i move the problem occours on the north.
I also tried to reproject all data in UTM 33 but the result was the same.

Is there a probelm with the CRS?

Is there a way to change the polygon grid so the each polygon is also changed relatively?

I hope someone can help[!
[image]